# Removing blank space between title and report in proc report for listings

Tags: sas, proc-report

I am looking for a method to remove a blank row between a title and body of a report.

```
title 'Title';
proc report data=have nocenter nowd headline headskip;
    column('--' col1 col2);
    
    define col1/ 'COL1';
    define col2/ 'COL2';
run;
```

The code above will create something like the following output:

```
Title

--------------------------------------------
COL1    COL2   
--------------------------------------------
```

I would like to remove blank row between the title and the upper dashed line of the report. I know I could do that using `compute before _page_` block and `line` statement in it but I would like to use titles. The output should look like this:

```
Title
--------------------------------------------
COL1    COL2   
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think you have to modify the style template, which style template are you using?

Comment: Is this in LISTING or HTML or what destination?

Comment: @Joe The output should be a listing.

Comment: If you are making plain old text output you could always post process the output to remove the extra line.